# c++ function declaration, constructor in header

Tags: c++, header

In the c++ header class,
There is a function that looks like

```
// AAA.h
void functioname() {}
```

I don't know why it has {} in the header file.
what is this??
I don't think it is a way to declare the function, is it a constructor?

Comment: It's an (empty) function body.

Comment: Have a look at our [C++ books list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10147399)